# Can't connect to remote db (Hostinger)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I've been having this error for a long time and I can't solve it. I have made my project locally, connecting to my database locally. Once finished I wanted to migrate my database manually since it is small to my hosting provider.

I have created the database, I have given it permissions to connect remotely and I have also checked that the connection data is correct.

A curiosity is that through mysql workbench it has allowed me to connect, the problem is clearly with my code, I am working with NodeJS (express). Another curiosity is that it appears to me as if I have successfully connected and 30 seconds later it gives me the following error:

```
    Node.js v18.12.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Listen on port 3000
Connection success!
node:events:491
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
at Connection._handleProtocolError 
(C:\Users\M\Desktop\Proyect\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:423:8)
at Protocol.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Protocol._delegateError 
(C:\Users\M\Desktop\Proyect\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:398:10)
at Protocol.handleNetworkError 
(C:\Users\M\Desktop\Proyect\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:371:10)
at Connection._handleNetworkError 
(C:\Users\M\Desktop\Proyect\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:418:18)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -4077,
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read',
fatal: true
}

Node.js v18.12.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is my connection script:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
user: process.env.DB_USER,
password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
});

connection.connect((error) => {
if(error){
    console.log('The connection error is: ' + error)
    return;
}
console.log('Connection success!')
})


module.exports = connection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  // Now use the connection to do stuff
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Result: " + result);
  });
});
```

You don't show the rest of your code, but you're not doing any query in that callback function, just outputting success. You need to do stuff inside that callback, or change the way you're exporting the connection. Have a look at createPool, and getConnection as I'm guessing you're actually wanting a persistent connection to your database?

Comment: Thank you! I solved it with createPool and then getConnection

Comment: You're welcome @MEVG - a word of caution though, make sure you've played close attention to your pool max concurrent connections limit. If you use a free provider, (elephantsql I used for postgresql), free accounts are limited to 5 just.

Comment: And if you don't have a limit (or have a high one) you'll end up wastefully chomping up system resources - which if you are on a google cloud VM or AWS will REALLY eat up your $$$. For elephant, I kept getting max connection reached error message littering my logs - It wasn't affecting functionality because it did then re-use one (old timed out, etc) - wasn't efficient. Turns out I had places where I was neither disposing of or storing the connection. I only fixed it once I made an effort to further understand promises and made my pool a global.

Comment: And when I switched away from elephant (before I fully grasped promises and made the change I indicated in the above comment) I was using an AWS database. Going from a monthly bill of a few pence (there was an occasion where I used a chunk too much bandwidth with some Distro ISOs, I had a 5$ bill to pay)... I thought I was on the free-forever type tier, but that bandwidth use was outside the free allocation.... but theres more....

Comment: Sadly, I had failed to spot the configuration that would notify me when some free allocation has run out or is running out, and/or the setting to either turn off feature X or notify me when the bill reaches its threshold (in my case it should have been anything over $5...

So, I used bandwidth, but in the same month, there was a seriously concerted effort to hack my site, and I hadn't yet fixed DB connections issue. So many connections where created, not closed, chewing up billions CPU eating RAM....

Comment: My bill was over $200. Yep - I'd configured the DB VM as a dynamic use case, to grow as needed, as my product scaled, so it would. I never imagining it would ever go bigger than a micro instance - and if it did, then it would coincide with my product making profit, so creeping into the paid area is fine! Epic fail in spotting this pitfall.... My bill was over $200. Yep - DB VM configured to grow as needed, never imagining it would ever go bigger than a micro instance - and if it did, then my product would be making profit so paid is fine! Epic fail in spotting this pitfall     